# How long is Final Fantasy VII?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

So far I have logged 24 hours in FF VII and I just finished disc 1. Anyway, keeping that in mind, how long can I expect it to take me to get through disc 2, and then disc 3?

Comment: I've seen speedrun times posted at about 8 hours for the entire game. On the flipside it took my cousin well over 99 hours to finish the entire game (maxing out everyone, golden choboco and all that) It all depends on how you choose to play and how fast you run through everything.

Comment: @Noctrine I agree it's very individual, but the concept of "game length in hours" is a common one in the video game world - a lot of games / game reviews mention expected gamethrough length. This is especially true for this question, where the asker already provided us with information about his or her pace, with the number of hours it took to finish the 1st disc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I remember well (which I may not, as it's been *>5 years* since I've played the game), the second disc is roughly as long as the first one, or perhaps a bit shorter. The third disc consists of the "endgame" bits -- the final dungeon, plus all the optional sidequests and bosses. Depending on how much of this side content you do, you could stretch your playtime quite far. If you just consider the main storyline, however, you're pretty much halfway through.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answerer mentions, the second disk is about the same length as the first, if a little shorter. In general though, I think the consensus is that FF7 is about 40 hours long, assuming you don't spend a long time in the endgame.

Answer (score 3):

According to the game's page on [HowLongToBeat.com](http://www.howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=3521), it took people around 40 hours to complete the main game. If you want to do everything and collect more stuff, you will end up with around 60 - 100 hours.

Now keep in mind that this highly depends on your playstyle and the result might vary from person to person.

HLTB has pretty nice statistics though and I personally do end up with similar play times.

Answer (score 0):

I beat the first disk in 13 hours and just beat the second disk 10 and a half hours later.
I am at this moment just starting the third disk, but this is A my second time playing up t the point where in the second disk Cloud find the truth about his past so the first disk I just flew through. Although this is my first time on the last disk. I came here seeing if any one new how long the last disk is. So this is a fairly long game I spent 23:33:46
on the first two with a much experience.