# How can I tell how long (more or less) it will take me to complete a game?

Tags: completion-time

I'm going down my huge backlog of unplayed Steam games and I'm thinking the best way to tackle the list is to go through the shortest games first and then concentrate on the 20+ hour ones. I'm wondering if there's a website or something else that has an estimated amount of gameplay time for games.

Is there anything like that?

Comment: Related meta discussion: [How should we handle questions about game completion time?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-game-completion-time)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use [HowLongToBeat.com](http://howlongtobeat.com/).

Answer (score 34):

You can use [HowLongToBeat.com](http://howlongtobeat.com/).  It collects stats from gamers and provides averages and so on:

> #### How it works?
>
> Check the column that best matches your play style, this is the median time it will take you to complete the game. You can also click on the games individually to really break down the stats.
>
> - **Main Story (Required)** - Gamer completed the main objectives, just enough to see the credits roll.
> - **Main Story and addition quests/medals/unlockables** - This gamer likes to take his time, discover and complete additional tasks not required.
> - **Completionist (100%)** - Gamers that get every achivement, every medal and conquer all that the game has to offer.

If there are a decent number of stats for the game in question then this likely provides a more accurate picture than a review would, unless you happen to find a reviewer who plays creepily similarly to you :P

(Hat tip to [Mehper C. Palavuzlar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/23983/6066).)

Comment: if you're a Completionist, you gonna have a bad time </meme> :D

Comment: i also wanted to add a good indication might be online guides. especially if you have been playing the game for a few hours already

Comment: Ha, the question merge makes this answer look ridiculous.  I suppose I'll leave it up unless it gets downvotes though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accurately assume how long a game will take other than looking up reviews and specifically searching for estimated completion times would be to have first hand experience with the game (if part of a series). There's no easy way to look at a game and immediately assume it will take X hours unless you have a lot of experience gaming.

Needless to say, RPGs are the longest to complete, typically ranging between 20 and 40+ hours (with Bethesda RPGs assume longer).

First person shooters are more varied, with some lasting around an hour (Rogue Warrior) but most lasting between 5-10 hours for the single player campaigns alone (Call of Duty, Battlefield, Bioshock, etc). Assume online multiplayer can consume 100's of hours if you're dedicated.

I'd go into more detail/depth but honestly it's a combination of the game, the competency of the player, the gaming experience of the player, and the style of gameplay (achievement hunter, casual, speed run, etc).

Answer (score -5):

A very vague question. Depends on the game. RPGs and Open-world games like GTA tend to be longest, anything marketed mainly at kids/movie tie-in tat generally the shortest. Some people see 8 hours as a long game, others want 40+ hours of gameplay. You really just need to look at a forum for whatever game it is, or google it.  There's no average.

Comment: He's asking how to *find out* how long a game will take; he's not asking for the completion time itself.

Comment: "Depends on the game" is exactly the reason why I wanted a resource that had some sort of rough estimates of how long it was taking people to complete specific games. How's that for not being vague?