# How can I tell how long (more or less) it will take me to complete a game?

Tags: completion-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a website that has estimated time duration for games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23966/is-there-a-website-that-has-estimated-time-duration-for-games)

I often want to know how long a game is so that I can decide whether or not to buy it, or even to decide if I've got enough free time available in the near-future to make it worth trying to play and complete over a weekend. Sometimes I even want to know just because I'm getting a little tired of the game and I want to have a sense of whether or not I'm nearing the end, so I can decide whether to tough it out or pack it in.

What are some good ways of determining how long a given game takes to complete, on average?