# What's the average time to finish Diablo III in Normal Mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell how long (more or less) it will take me to complete a game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23966/how-can-i-tell-how-long-more-or-less-it-will-take-me-to-complete-a-game)

How long does it take for an average player to finish all acts in Normal Mode?

Only a reference from Blizzard or another strong reference could answer this, **please note that I'm not asking to post an opinion**.

I'm considering buying it to my wife but I know she's not a big fan of [Diablo's *endless "replayability"*](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5270828409), so I'm trying to know if it is worthy.

Comment: 1 hour there's even an achievement for this. But if you meant for a level 1. then between 5 to 22 hours.

Comment: I am nearing the end of Act III at 8 hours. I dilly dally though.

Comment: Check this question/answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23966/how-can-i-tell-how-long-more-or-less-it-will-take-me-to-complete-a-game

Comment: You should end Normal at level 30, nightmare at level 50, hell at level 60 inferno at level 60. The average time to clear normal usually is 7-8hours

Comment: @MichelAyres 7-8 hours for normal is fast.  10-12 would be a typical range.

Comment: Just wondering how exactly is anyone going to be able to collect stats for all players around the world...

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty subjective and there's no real "best" answer, but since I am in a similar situation I figured I'd share.

My wife is a casual gamer. She likes to take frequent breaks, reads everything thoroughly, explores the entire map, and spends a fair amount of time weighing gear and skill decisions to get the playstyle feeling right.

At that pace, it took us about 20 hours to beat normal the first time through. I'd guess that maybe 2 of those hours were spent AFK doing one thing or another, though.

On my solo character I finished Act IV in 10 hours. I still explored a lot, but skipped all of the cinematics.

Comment: One thing or another eh? ;)

Comment: Skipping cinematics is a drop in the bucket compared to the time it takes to explore even one bonus cave.

Comment: @dpatchery Your wife is almost like mine =)